# How to show a VSCode file’s change history that isn’t a got repository

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a file that is only local, and I wanted to see if there is a way to show the changes or last saves made to the file.

Comment: Why not just create a local repository?

Answer (score 1):

If you keep vscode up to date in recent update devs introduced local history that is independent of git. You can find it by searching for `Local History` in command pallet (you can access it with `CTRL+Shift+P` by default)

Answer (score 0):

You can install an extension named ["Local History"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history).
[image]

When you click a file, a comparaison with the current version is displayed.

[image]